# Hiding opacity of content with angular with

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to hide the 3 bicycles when you click the left arrow so that I can transition it to the next 3 bicycles from my app.js products object. I tried ng-hide, but it makes them disappear causing the two arrows to snap next to each other like in screenshot below. If I hide opacity, they will stay where they are and then I can change the images while invisible.
Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='formApp'>

<head>
    <title>Bicycle App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class='row'>

                <div class='col-md-12'>

                    <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"><span>&nbsp;{{"Bike Shop"}}</span></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                <!-- end class not needed -->
                <div class="chooseTitle">
                    Choose Your Bicycle
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                <!-- you missed md from offset, end class not needed -->
                <div class="products" ng-controller="BikeController">
                  <div class="row">
             <div ng-repeat="product in products | limitTo:-3">
     <div class="col-md-1" id="leftArrow" ng-click="leftArrowClick($index)"><a ng-href="#"><img ng-src="images/leftarrow.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
<div class="bikesandtitles"> 

                  <div id="bikeTitle" class="col-md-3 text-center" ng-style="{ 'translucent': $index !== selectedIndex }">
                  {{product.manufacturer}}
                  <img id="bikePic" ng-src="{{product.image}}" ng-style="{ 'translucent': $index !== selectedIndex }">
                  </div>
                       </div>
                       </div><!-- end ng-repeat products -->
                   <div class="col-md-1" id="rightArrow"><a ng-href="#" ><img ng-src="images/rightarrow.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>



</div>
                </div><!--End controller-->




    </div>



    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bikeimageslider.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('formApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('BikeController',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.bikeSlide = false;
$scope.leftArrowClick = function(index){

  $scope.selectedIndex = index;

};

$scope.products = [
{
manufacturer: "Trek",
image: 'images/bike1.jpg'
}, 
{
manufacturer: "Mongoose",
image: 'images/bike2.jpg'

},
{   

    manufacturer: "Portlandia",
image: 'images/bike3.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Giant",
image: 'images/bike4.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Framed",
image: 'images/bike5.jpg'
},
{
manufacturer: "Windsor",
image: 'images/bike6.jpg'
}
];


this.form = {};
this.addForm = function(product){

};

}]);
```

app.css

```
.header{
    font-style:italic;
background-color:black;
height:60px;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:40px;


}
.header .fa {font-style:italic;
}
.bikeSelector{
color:green;
}
.chooseTitle{

font-size:60px;

}

.products{
color:  #1E90FF  ;
text-align:center;
font-size:40px;

}
#bikePic{

height:100%;
width:100%;

}
#leftArrow, #rightArrow{
width:120px;

}


.translucent {
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

Comment: You could use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate for your ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily hide the content with `visibility:hidden`. Like so

```
<div ng-class="{ hidden: isTransitioning }" ..>...</div>

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And in the onClick handler of the arrows you can place.

```
scope.isTransitioning = true;
```

And after the transition is done you can reset the value

```
scope.isTransitioning = false;
```

Comment: I added your suggested code and I thought I did it right. I the scope.isTransitioning in the leftArrowClick() function and I got it to disappear onclick, but when it disappears, it looks like the second image I posted where the arrows come together instead of staying in place.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-style` or `ng-class` might be helpful here:

```
<div ng-style="{ 'translucent': $index !== selectedIndex }" ..>...</div>

.translucent {
    opacity: 0.5
}

In function:
$scope.leftArrowClick = function (index){
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: I added your code, but nothing happens onclick. I updated the code above. Also did you mean to put (index) insteadof function(index) because the console doesn't like leftArrowClick(index). I wrote it like I think you meant, but either way it doesn't do anything on click now. The products stay visible. Any ideas? See updated code above

Comment: yes, i meant the other way. corrected the mistake. as per your updated code: you need to pass `$index` in html too. `leftArrowClick($index)`, also you need to move the `ng-repeat` above the `ng-click`. my code is just sample. you need to make some changes of yourself too.

Comment: I updated my code above again to reflect the $index. I also put in ng-repeat above ng-click, but I'm getting nothing onclick. What am I missing. See updated code above.

Comment: you missed this: `<div ng-repeat="product in products | limitTo:-3"></div>` your `ng-repeat` ends with that `div`

Comment: I see what you mean, but if I add ng-repeat before the leftarrow image, its, repeating the arrow too. See updated code and new image above

Comment: ah. need to rethink. you can remove that `ng-repeat` and just use `somevalue++` for left arrow and `somevalue--` for right arrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117014/discussion-between-maddog-and-user6680).